# Vectorization of Matrix Quadratics in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, vector, vectorization

I am trying to "vectorize" this loop in Matlab for computational efficiency

```
for t=1:T
   j=1;
   for m=1:M
      for n=1:N
         y(t,j) = v{m,n} + data(t,:)*b{m,n} +  data(t,:)*f{m,n}*data(t,:)';
         j=j+1;
      end
   end
end
```

Where `v` is a (`M` x `N`) cell of scalars. `b` is a (`M` x `N`) cell of (`K` x 1) vectors. `f` is a (`M` x `N`) cell of (`K` x `K`) matrices. `data` is a (`T` x `K`) array.

To give an example of what I mean the code I used to vectorize the same loop without the quadratic term is:

```
B = [reshape(cell2mat(v)',1,N*M);cell2mat(reshape(b'),1,M*N)];
X = [ones(T,1),data];
y = X*B;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested here was the solution I found

```
f = f';
tMat = blkdiag(f{:})+(blkdiag(f{:}))';
y2BB = [reshape(cell2mat(v)',1,N*M);...
        cell2mat(reshape(b',1,M*N));...
        reshape(diag(blkdiag(f{:})),K,N*M);...
        reshape(tMat((tril(tMat,-1)~=0)),sum(1:K-1),M*N)]; 
y2YBar = [ones(T,1),data,data.^2];

jj=1;
kk=1;
ll=1;
for k=1:sum(1:K-1)
    y2YBar = [y2YBar,data(:,jj).*data(:,kk+jj)];
    if kk<(K-ll)
        kk=kk+1;
    else
        kk=1;
        jj=jj+1;
        ll=ll+1;
    end
end
y = y2YBar*y2BB;
```

Comment: The last loop is sloppy but my brain was hurting. Let me know if you think of a more efficient way to add those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most vectorized form targeted for performance -

```
% Extract as multi-dim arrays
vA = reshape([v{:}],M,N);
bA = reshape([b{:}],K,M,N);
fA = reshape([f{:}],K,K,M,N);

% Perform : data(t,:)*f{m,n} for all iterations
data_f_mult = reshape(data*reshape(fA,K,[]),T,K,M,N);

% Now there are three parts :
% v{m,n}
% data(t,:)*b{m,n}
% data(t,:)*f{m,n}*data(t,:)';

% Compute those parts one by one
parte1 = vA(:).';
parte2 = data*reshape(bA,[],M*N);

parte3 = zeros(T,M*N);
for t = 1:T
    parte3(t,:) = data(t,:)*reshape(data_f_mult(t,:,:),K,[]);
end

% Finally sum those up and to present in desired format permute dims
sums = bsxfun(@plus, parte1, parte2 + parte3);
out = reshape(permute(reshape(sums,T,M,N),[1,3,2]),[],M*N);
```

Comment: Nice work! I'll test which is most efficient and choose that answer. Mine loops far less times, considering for my application T=152, N=K=3, and M=8.

Comment: Yea, your code ran at 0.025 and mine at 0.008 about. Thanks again for your answer.